# Add new column in data frame with vlookup values

Tags: r, database, dataframe, vlookup

I have a data frame in R.

```
Col1  Col2

1      21

1      20
```

I want the below output.

```
Col1  Col2   Output

1     21     21

1     20     21
```

Essentially, I want to apply a lookup on Col1 for Col2 and store the result in output column. This will ensure that for the same input in column 1, the higher of the two values in column will be picked in the lookup.

I have tried several ways to do this but none seems to be working.

Updated Data Frame -

```
Col1   Col2    Output

1      21       21

1      20       21

12     20       20

12     19       20
```

Comment: "the higher of the two values in column" - is this in relation to its index in the column, or its value?

Answer (score 0):

We can do a group by 'Col1' and update the `max` value of 'Col2'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(Col1) %>%
    mutate(Ouput = max(Col2)) %>%
    ungroup
```

Comment: Hi , the above code worked for Col1 = 1. But when I tried on the below table, Col1 Col2
1 21
1 20
12 20
12 19, it gave NA for Col1 = 12. Also, Col1 does not have incremental values starting from 1. It has different values.

Comment: @SM9 your comment is broken

Comment: @SM9 Please update your post with a reproducible example

Comment: post updated with new data frame

Comment: @SM9 updated the answer

Comment: Thanks. I think group by and max would work. I will try tomorrow on the original data.